# Where does Sparkle save its preferences/defaults?

Tags: cocoa, auto-update, sparkle

I want to test the functionality that Sparkle provides like "Ignore this version", "Remind me later" etc. But I can't seem to find these stored anywhere in user defaults.

Where does Sparkle store these values?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it seems to use `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`. For my case, I was looking in the wrong place for user defaults.